# Is there any python ORM, that provide "clear" model architecture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm

I have a quite experience with PHP and c# development and I am looking into learning the python. I wanted to practice data storage and retrieval and I am crying when I see how most of python ORMs handle the model layer.

It seems normal in python ORMs, that a model entity does a lot of work – it is not only a data container (what I believe it should be and nothing else), but it also for some libraries holds database connection ([peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#model-definition) – yes, you can use an entity without db and bind it later, but you still have to use the entity for data retrieval...) or has some common metadata object from which they inherit ([declarative_base in SQLalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html)). In some libraries, the entity class is used for data [retrieval](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#storing-data), [filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), [storage](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#tutorial), or [deletion](https://docs.ponyorm.org/working_with_entity_instances.html#deleting-an-object). Similar concepts can be seen in other ORM libraries like [django-orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/), [tortoise-orm](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm#getting-started), [pony-orm](https://docs.ponyorm.org/entities.html).

This gives the entity class too much responsibility and binds the entity (and the whole data service layer) with a specific library implementation. It also breaks the single responsibility principle, separation of concepts, makes testing much harder, makes dependency injection quite unusable, and probably many other things I cannot think of now. Even though the mentioned libraries are generally nice and do everything you need I cannot get over this basic thing...

I was expecting to see some manager / data service layer, that would be responsible for data storage and retrieval. Entities would be close-to-plain objects not knowing anything about database layer (like [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#example-time) or [doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html) entities). Does anything like this exist in python? Why are such (anti) patterns are so common in python libraries?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Author of peewee here. As you note, Peewee has a query-builder API that is not coupled to the underlying database connection, but that is simply the foundation on which the more tightly-coupled models layer is built. This is what 99.99% of everyone uses, as far as I can tell. For me, I look at: what am I trying to do here, and how can I get it done as simply as possible, with minimal boilerplate or configuration. This follows the 80-20 rule (although for Peewee users its probably closer to 99-1), where the APIs exposed align exactly with what the user is trying to do. From the feedback I receive, it seems that other people have similar goals, and like the simplicity of Peewee.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it might work (and obviously works) for most of cases (users). But for me coupling logic and data container does not seem like a good engineering technique (due to reasons I have described in my question). I did check out the query builder and it seems it still uses model entities for basic CRUD operations. I wonder why this is such a common way in Python, whereas I cannot think about any mature c # (or php) ORM that does not separate these layers ...

Comment: I think that when people want a service layer, they tend to build it atop the models/APIs provided by the ORM. In this way they treat the models like very thin struct types with convenience methods for storage/retrieval.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing - using peewee and converting between peewee's models and mine plain object models. Thanks for your reply and for the library, appart from my issue with this service layer I found it to be very nice.